# Knex + Webpack: Cannot find module "../package.json"

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, knex.js

I'm getting this issue with `knex` and `webpack`.

```
Error: Cannot find module "../package.json"

Knex.VERSION = __webpack_require__(!(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module \"../package.json\""); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }())).version;
```

Here's my `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: './',
    filename: 'main.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I don't understand why the `json` loader isn't working.